# jQuery Slideshow Transition "Skipping"

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, transition

***Edit: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lisa_yael/t5qgjo9L/1/

My website has a slideshow that plays automatically, but that can also be controlled via arrows on either side to go to the different slides manually.  However, whenever I play the slideshow for the first time (i.e. when I first go on to the website), it has a weird "skipping" effect between slides instead of the normal smooth transition.  I am not sure what is going wrong.

Here is the code I am using for the slideshow; thanks in advance:

```
<script 
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>

var slideIndex = 1;
var t;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {

  slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  clearTimeout(t);
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  console.log(slideIndex);
}

function currentSlide(n) {

  showSlides(slideIndex = n);

}

function showSlides(n) {

  var i;

  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  if (n == undefined) {
    n = ++slideIndex;
  }

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }



  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

    slides[i].style.display = "none";

  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";


  t = setTimeout(showSlides, 2000);

}
</script>
```

Comment: Please include some of your markup and stylesheets to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be best if you included all of your code directly as a code snippet using the appropriate button in the editor.

Comment: either you should provide a link or http://jsfiddle.net/ example so that developers are able to understand your problem in 5-10 min. We are not here to give our 1-2 hours to just reproduce your issue.

Comment: Just updated to add the jsfiddle.  Thanks